# Why JMeter reponse time is more important than response time in browser

Tags: jmeter

I read some related post concerning the same problem but i did have concerns.
In fact,jmeter reponse time is the time  maked by the server to send and analyse reponse and the browser page load time is client side. Added to that JMeter send request in sequence and the browser send many at the same time it depends from browser to another. Even that requests are sending in the same time normally the response time will be very close for the two case. I'm attending to find response time for manual tests with browser more important than JMeter but unfortuanately there is a huge diffrence (even 3 minutes)  that make me wonder the cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think because of following reasons,

1. JMeter is server side load testing tool (means we are worried about server response and not about client i.e. browser)
2. When we see resonse in browser, sequence is, raw text response is parsed first, css applied, any other styling features are applied, JS if any starts running and then you see a complete web page loaded but all this is client activity and not server
3. When we are interested in, why response from server is slow? or what is the server response at specific load? then we use jmeter which will give time from request sent to server till we get first byte of response which is server response time + latency
4. Thus Jmeter response time is less than browser and is more important in server side load testing

But there are plugins available which will help you simulate sending parallel requests and ajax requests to server, by default Jmeter sends requests sequentially but plugins and tweaks are available for your need.

I hope this clarified your doubt. :)

Comment: Thanks for your response, I understand the reasons  but i still have one doubt. Even if the browser is client side with all (css, js,etc), those elements are located in the server side and to show it in the web page we need to load related files. So, why the time of loading css, js on the browser is less than requests sent by JMeter. Does the browser load only the need of css or javascript not the hole files.

Comment: loading complete css,js etc. files was case before some years but nowadays as you know ajax requests are coming in picture. so browser renders only required portion and not whole in beginning and thats why client side rendering time should not be counted in response time as it will not predict actual response time.